# Recursive setting of folder permissions with InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a folder tree that I copy to C:\ProgramData The software that I am installing (don't blame me for this, I did not architect, write or design it) requires full control for everyone for this data.

So I put the following line in [Files] sectionL

```
Source: "C:\ProgramData\PFPS\MapDataServer\*"; DestDir: "C:\ProgramData\PFPS\FalconViewCommand"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Permissions: everyone-full; Excludes: "*.LDF"
```

yes, this does give everyone full control of each individual file, but the program needs to create files and the folder permissions (directory) are not set for everyone.

I tried to add a [Dirs] section but that did not work:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "C:\ProgramData\PFPS\FalconViewCommand"; Flags: uninsalwaysuninstall; Permissions: everyone-full
```

What do the guru's say?

Comment: The `[Dirs]` entry should work, except that you should be using `{commonappdata}` instead of hard-coding `C:\ProgramData`.  (And yes, granting permissions like this is generally a sign of a badly designed app.)  Have you tried completely uninstalling the app first and ensuring that this folder doesn't exist before running the install?

Comment: @Miral how would graning permissions to ProgramData be a bad design? It is recommended place to store system-wide application settings...

Comment: Firstly, because most people default to wanting system-wide settings because they simply haven't thought sufficiently about it to realise that people might want to customise them on a user level.  (It's easier, not better.)  Secondly because anything that's made writable to all users is inherently corruptable by all users (or a virus running in their account), increasing the effect of such damage.  And finally because anything readable to all users is a possible violation of privacy.  Obviously not all of these arguments apply to everything, but it's surprising how little people even think.

Comment: I get situations with clients who have strict folder security and auditing. There's a free tool to check hierarchical permissions which is really useful (and simple) - http://www.directorypermissions.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have been doing is the following RUN at the end, I was finding that the Dirs was not working (yes, I always do a full unistall, when testing install scripts), otherwise how do you know what will happen when the product ships?

I agree with you about {commonappdata} but I am trying to remove randomness till I get to the bottom of the issue.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
[Run]
Filename: "C:\Windows\System32\icacls.exe"; Parameters: "C:\ProgramData\PFPS\FalconViewCommand /grant:r Users:(OI)(CI)F"; WorkingDir: "{tmp}"; Description: "Changing Directory Permissions"; StatusMsg: "Changing Directory Permissions"
```

Comment: Minor point but an uninstall may not be the same as a clean install.

Comment: Note that icacls isn't available in Windows XP. The one copied from Win7 won't run (not a win32 app, must be written in .NET or something) and the one from Windows Server 2003 has only limited functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
[Dirs]    
Name:"{app}\"; Permissions:everyone-modify
```

Comment: Never do this for `{app}` or any other location that can hold executables. It's still dangerous (but less of an attack surface)  for shared data/settings depending on how they're used.